# No pg_hba.conf entry for postgresql 9.5 & ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to a hosted postgesql database from my AWS server running ubuntu. However, I keep getting the error:

`error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xx.xx", user "db_user", database "db_name", SSL off`

So I edited my `pg_hba.conf` file (note the lines marked as `new entry`:

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                peer

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     peer
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    host    db_name         db_user         xx.xx.xx.xx             md5 (new entry)
    host    all             all             all                     md5 (new entry)
    #IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I then restarted my postgresql and retried to connect
Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

this:

```
host    db_name         db_user         xx.xx.xx.xx             md5 (new entry)
```

to that:

```
host    db_name         db_user         all             md5 (new entry)
```

or

```
host    db_name         db_user         0.0.0.0/0             md5 (new entry)
```